# What kind of API is AWS' DynamoDb API? Is it REST, SOAP or something else?

Tags: amazon-web-services, rest, soap, web-applications, amazon-dynamodb

I'm creating an app that queries a DynamoDB to return information for a project I'm working on.

Just wondering what kind of API the AWS DynamoDB uses when you're writing a program using the SDK (in my case I'm using Java).

I'm not creating any GET or PUT requests or anything as the SDK seems to sort it all out for me behind the scenes, but I'm curious how it actually works.

I've tried looking on the docs but couldn't really find anything so wondered if you folks knew.

For example, a section of code here shows the function being called in the AWS code examples for the Java SDK.

```
QueryResponse response = ddb.query(queryReq);
```

Thanks!

Comment: You might want to look at the API documentation for DynamoDB: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/Welcome.html

Comment: Hi @Dunedan, as mentioned in the post, I have looked through the docs, it mentions using HTTP but doesn't mention that it's a SOAP or REST API specifically

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The DynamoDB API uses HTTP (or HTTPS) for the requests, with both request and response bodies encoded as JSON; The HTTP headers include the operation's type and well as an authorization signature for the request, and the request body includes the different parameters of the operation (e.g., the UpdateItem operation needs to say which table is involved, which item, how its attributes are modified, various conditions, etc. - all of this is described as a JSON object). A single HTTP connection may be reused for multiple requests. You can see an overview of this protocol with examples here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Programming.LowLevelAPI.html

Obviously, this protocol is **not** SOAP, which is completely different beast.
In my opinion it's also not a good idea to call it "REST" (check out a definition of REST in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer). Although REST also uses HTTP for the transport, it doesn't use it in quite the same way, and the DynamoDB API has a lot of details not specified by REST. But they are very close in the sense that both are HTTP-based protocols, and you can easily implement them using any HTTP client or library.